# How to use text-overflow:ellipsis with tinymce

Tags: tinymce, css

I have a master detail type view setup where you can enter data on the right side (detail) and it will show in a summary on the left side (detail). I accomplished this view using CSS and jQuery. All of the data is coming from a mysql database.

The problem is caused by the html tags that tinymce inserts into the textarea. When I try to display it using the `text-overflow:ellipsis;` CSS it doesn't put in the ellipsis.

CSS:

```
.OverflowData {
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/5evPs/) is a stripped down jsFiddle with the resulting data with the tinymce html tags added and what happens on the left side.

Now [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/5evPs/1/) is a version where I stripped out the `<p>` tags and the ellipsis shows properly.

So my question is: is it possible to have the summary and ellipsis show properly in the first case or must I strip out all of the html from the tinymce textarea beforehand?

I am open to other suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The settings have to be on the immediate parent so this works when added to your sample (note the 'p' in the selector):

```
.OverflowData p {
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;    
}
```

Comment: This then adds the ellipsis to every paragraph. I want to display the data as if there were no paragraph tags giving me the result in my second jsFiddle link.

Comment: When I add the new CSS (leaving the old one to keep the div size) it only shows one paragraph. Here's the jsFiddle update: http://jsfiddle.net/gbnAS/. If you have paragraphs nested in paragraphs just change it to .OverflowData > p to only select the immediate children of the div.

Comment: Great it does work after all. The first time I did it I just added the p after .OverflowData without keeping the original class for the div.